# Umbraco 4.7 - nodes created at root level of site are saved to umbracoNode table with level = 2

Tags: c#, umbraco

Here's a simplified version of my Content tree.

```
- Content
    - Articles
        - Article 1
    - About Us
```

Let's assume I add 2 nodes, one as a child of Articles and the other at the root level.  My tree would now look like this.

```
- Content
    - Articles
        - Article 1
        - Article 2
    - About Us
    - Terms
```

Both `Article 2` and `Terms` are saved to the umbracoNode table with "level" set to 2.  This is not the correct level for `Terms`; it's level should be 1.

This is causing publishing to fail, specifically at umbraco.cms.presentation.editContent.Publish:

```cs
if (_document.Level == 1 
    || new cms.businesslogic.web.Document(_document.Parent.Id).Published)
{
    // Code that publishes the node
}
```

What's happening is that since level DOES NOT equal 1, it evaluates the 2nd part of the conditional.  Once the `Document` is instantiated with the current node's parent id (-1), it checks for cmsContentVersion entries with that id.  However, it's the root node, and nothing exists in cmsContentVersion for the root, so it goes kaboom.

A few things that may or may not be of interest:

- We are in the process of upgrading from v3.6 -> v4.7
- Right-Clicking the node and publishing works
- The link to the document after right-clicking and publishing is simply `#`, which is also incorrect.  I'm unsure if this is related or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix actually ended up being pretty simple, hope this saves someone a headache.

I simply had to update `level` to 0 for the root note (it was 1 prior to udpating it).

```sql
UPDATE umbracoNode 
SET [level] = 0 
WHERE id = -1
```

I assume this was some artifact of version 3 that, for some reason, wasn't addressed earlier in the upgrade.